# I want to make an event to switch connections enter exit blocks

Tags: anylogic

I have a model with 6 enter blocks and 5 exit blocks I want to make an event, that changes the connections from for example. First 5 agents from exit1 to enter1 or 2,3,4,5 and the agents with is 6-10  from exit1 to enter2 or 3.
I want to use the event to get different routes for the agents based on their Id.

so i could call the code in every Exit block an need as many counters as exits ? so i could use counter1 for exit1 counter2 for exit2 to sende the same 5 agents trough the same routes ? For example so if i want to send agent 10-15 do i use:

```
counter++; if (counter>=10 && <=15) { // send to some enter block } else { // send to another block }
```

??

Answer (score 1):

An event is the wrong approach. You can use a variable of type `int` named `counter` next to the `exit1`.

In the `exit1` code box "on enter", write:

```
counter++;
if (counter>5) {
    // send to some enter block
} else {
    // send to another block
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so i could call the code in every Exit block an need as many counters as exits ? so i could use counter1 for exit1 counter2 for exit2 to sende the same 5 agents trough the same routes ? For example so if  i want to send agent 10-15 do i use:                                                                                                                           
counter++;
if (counter>=10 && <=15) {
    // send to some enter block
} else {
    // send to another block
}

Comment: i thought i could use a function like this for my enter and exits blocks so i always just need to use 5 functions and the function 1 at exit 1 etc. I have built this code :                   
  if (agent.getAuftragsId() >= 1 && agent.getAuftragsId() <= 9) {
    agent.enterMaschine1.take(agent);


} else if (agent.getAuftragsId() >= 10 && agent.getAuftragsId() <= 13) {
    agent.enterMaschine2.take(agent);


} else if (agent.getAuftragsId() >= 14 && agent.getAuftragsId() <= 15) {
    agent.enterMaschine3.take(agent);
} Is the code correct ?

Comment: Pls understand how SOF works: it is not a forum with back-and-forth comms. It is a knowledge base building itself from questions. Always open new issues for new questions :)